# How to check if command -v $1 >/dev/null 2>&1; is false?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm looking for a proper way to check if a command does **not** exist. I've read through [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212). So far I came up with:

```
command_exists () {
    command -v $1 >/dev/null 2>&1;
}

if command_exists aws; then
    echo # null
else
    brew install awscli
fi
```

There has to be a way to only have one if clause like:

```
if ! command_exists aws; then
    brew install awscli
fi
```

*update:* nevermind, above solution works.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution not using bash `which` util?

Comment: And how is this code not working for you?

Comment: `:` (just a colon) or `true` are better than `echo`, which has the side effect of printing a spurious line of output.

Comment: @tripleee: May be he was looking for an alternate solution unlike the one above which has a `bash` function written.

Comment: @Inian Or maybe he didn't try the code, and it already works.  Occam's razor would dictate my interpretation, but the question is obviously too vague, and should be updated, which only the OP can do.

Comment: @mles Maybe delete this question then?

Comment: I can't delete it since it has answers. I would just leave it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar function defined and there’s no reason why your snippet of shell code shouldn’t work.

```
if ! command_exists aws; then
    brew install awscli
fi
```

If you prefer, you can shorten this like so:

```
command_exists aws || brew install awscli
```